# return the array of the selected id after the edit

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm sorry but i kind of find some difficulties while editing my data , the problem is when i click the button edit, it works but when you go back to the previous page, it's like the id isn't stocked anymore so the array stays unknowns of this specific id.

Here is it's code:

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';

$id = $_GET['quotauser'];
if (isset($id)) {
  extract($crud->getQUOTA($id));
}
include_once 'headerQ.php'; 
?>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="container">
  <a href="add-quota.php?add-quota" class="btn btn-large btn-info">
    <i  class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> &nbsp; Add Quota
  </a>
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div><br />

<div class="container">
    <table class='table table-bordered table-responsive'>
      <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>QTANAME</th>
        <th>SRVNAME</th>
        <th>QTAVALUE</th>
        <th colspan="3" align="center">Actions</th>
      </tr>
      <?php
      $query = "SELECT quota.* FROM quota,user WHERE user.id=quota.id_user AND quota.id_user= '.$id.' ";
      $records_per_page = 10;
      $newquery = $crud->paging($query, $records_per_page);
      $crud->quotaID($newquery);
      ?>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="10" align="center">
          <div class="pagination-wrap">
            <?php $crud->paginglink($query, $records_per_page); ?>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<?php include_once 'footer.php'; ?>
```

and when the button show quota is clicked, the page that contains quota  contain two options edit and delete

[image]

and the edit button takes u to this page

[image]

**Edit's code is :**

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
if (isset($_POST['btn-update'])) {

  $id = $_GET['edit_quota'];
  $QTANAME = $_POST['QTANAME'];
  $SRVNAME = $_POST['SRVNAME'];
  $QTAVALUE = $_POST['QTAVALUE'];

  if ($crud->updateQ($id, $QTANAME, $SRVNAME, $QTAVALUE)) {
    $msg = "<div class='alert alert-info'>
            <strong>WOW!</strong> Quota was updated successfully <a href='UserQuota.php'>HOME</a>!
            </div>";
  } else {
    $msg = "<div class='alert alert-warning'>
            <strong>SORRY!</strong> ERROR while updating Quota !
            </div>";
  }
}

if (isset($_GET['edit_quota'])) {
  $id = $_GET['edit_quota'];
  extract($crud->getQUOTA($id));
}
?>
<?php include_once 'headerQ.php'; ?>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="container">
<?php
if (isset($msg)) {
  echo $msg;
}
?>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div><br />
<div class="container">
  <form method='post'>
    <table class='table table-bordered'>
      <tr>
        <td>QTANAME</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='QTANAME' class='form-control' value="<?php echo $QTANAME; ?>" required></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SRVNAME</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='SRVNAME' class='form-control' value="<?php echo $SRVNAME; ?>" required></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>QTAVALUE</td>
        <td><input type='number' name='QTAVALUE' class='form-control' value="<?php echo $QTAVALUE; ?>" required></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn-update">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>  Update this Record
          </button>
          <a href="UserQuota.php" class="btn btn-large btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></i> &nbsp; CANCEL</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>

<?php include_once 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: **Note:** using [`extract()`](http://php.net/extract) may lead to some security issues.